# Keyboard working only when other keys are pressed

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, windows-installer

My laptop is being weird. I have a computer kit, so I could undo everything, but I want to be sure it isn't some default software downloaded on my PC. But my keys <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> work only when another button is pressed. So I can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and it will work. I can even press like a button on my num pad or a letter. But when I press the key <kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> alone, it won’t work. But then randomly it will start working again. Then will stop working after a little bit.

Here is my system info:

```
System Information report written at: 06/23/18 09:53:08
System Name: MSI
[System Summary (C:\Users\xavie\OneDrive\Desktop\System.nfo)]

Item    Value
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name MSI
System Manufacturer Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
System Model    GT72VR 6RD
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  1785.1
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2601 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. E1785IMS.10B, 7/11/2016
SMBIOS Version  3.0
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   On
PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.17134.1"
User Name   MSI\xavie
Time Zone   Pacific Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   16.0 GB
Available Physical Memory   12.6 GB
Total Virtual Memory    18.8 GB
Available Virtual Memory    13.9 GB
Page File Space 2.88 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support   Elevation Required to View
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

The keyboard is 1½ years old.

Comment: Is the mystery laptop old enough to have detritus in the keyboard which could do with being cleaned out?

Comment: Sorry, I was figuring out why I couldn't comment but realied I was on my other account... But! the answer is... Kind of old. It is only about 1.5 years old. Unless you count that as old

Comment: Power off the laptop. With it opened out, turn it upside-down and shake it a little bit. Do some crumbs, pet hairs, or such, come out? They could have been interfering with the action of the keys, so it is time to [clean the keyboard](https://www.howtocleanthings.com/how-to-clean-a-laptop-keyboard/). Some people suggest that using compressed air only blows the dirt further in to the computer, some people say that using a vacuum cleaner generates static electricity which can zap the computer.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Yea I shook it the only thing that came out were tiny specs but now x and z are working fine. Thank you very much. hehe. I will go buy a compressed air keyboard cleaner. Again thank you! And do you have an explanation for the keys working when others are pressed? Or you have no clue?

Comment: You're welcome :) At a guess, pressing other keys could have flexed the keyboard a tiny but sufficient amount to allow those keys to work. You might have successfully dislodged more than the tiny specks, and the other bits are hanging around under some other keys now <shudder>. With some laptops, it is really easy to carefully take the keyboard out for replacement/cleaning - if you're lucky yours is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power off the laptop. With it opened out, turn it upside-down and shake it a little bit. Do some crumbs, pet hairs, or such, come out? They could have been interfering with the action of the keys, so it is time to [clean the keyboard](https://www.howtocleanthings.com/how-to-clean-a-laptop-keyboard/).

With some laptops, it is really easy to carefully take the keyboard out for replacement/cleaning - if you're lucky yours is like that.

Note that some people suggest that using compressed air only blows the dirt further in to the computer, some people say that using a vacuum cleaner generates static electricity which can zap the computer. Either way it *could* cause a new problem, but I don't see any people reporting *actual* problems from doing either.